# XPath to select a node by position based on another node's position

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, xpath

Using XPath, is there a way to ***select a node whose position equals the position of another node from a different parent***?

Concretely, let's say I have this simple HTML table (also available in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fz254v7k/)):

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col A</th>
      <th>Col B</th>
      <th>Col C</th>
      <th>Col D</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Field A</td>
      <td>Field B</td>
      <td>Field C</td>
      <td>Field D</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Let's say I want to select the 2nd column's `td`, i.e. `<td>Field B</td>`, but I want to express it by looking for the column whose header is `"Col B"`. In other words, I want to select `<td>Field B</tb>`, which has `position()=2`, but rather than hardcoding the 2, I want to derive it by looking for the `th` whose text is `"Col B"`.

Of course I can select that `th`, using

```
$x("//th[text()='Col B']")
```

But now I want to extract that `th`'s `position()` (which equals 2) and use that to select the `td` by its position.

Conceptually, I would like to do something like the following, except it's not valid XPath:

```
$x("//td[position()=//th[text()='Col B'][position()]")
```

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the number of `th` elements that precede the `th` whose string value is any given value, say, `"Col B"`, and use that count to select the corresponding `td` element:

```
//td[count(//th[.='Col B']/preceding-sibling::th)+1]
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  Thanks for such a well-formulated, interesting question.